# Trigger sort with icon for primeng turbo table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

For PrimeNG Turbo Table, can you make sort only trigger when the sort icons are clicked?

Right now, it triggers whenever I click anywhere int he header cell.  I'd like to just trigger when clicking the icons.

I was thinking this may be possible with StopPropogation() somewhere at the icon level...but that may stop the whole sort

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move `pSortableColumn` directive into `<p-sortIcon ...>`

```
<th>Year
<p-sortIcon [pSortableColumn]="'year'" [field]="'year'"></p-sortIcon>
</th>
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ajhukr)